# Laravel and package spatie/laravel-translatable -> Make search query for special character

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-translatable

I use the package Spatie/laravel-translatable to store my translated data in json in the database.

I have a column title :

```
{
  "fr":"L\u2019\u00e9quipe",
  "en":"Team",
  "de":"Team"
}
```

As you can see, with the package, special characters are transformed into unicode.

When I want to search, it does not work (it's logical, because I'm looking for the word `équipe` but in the database it says `\u00e9quipe`)

```
$search = $request->get('search')

Events::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->published()->get();
```

How to search through Unicode for it to work?

Thank you

Comment: If the column title field contains the raw value `L\u2019\u00e9quipe`, that is a string containing escaped characters. Why don't you use UTF8 all the way through?

Answer (score 1):

in the  Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations trait
use
`$this->attributes[$key] = json_encode($translations, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

instead of
`$this->attributes[$key] = $this->asJson($translations);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Taha Elkholy
maybe in the model, User.php for example, we override the asJson() method, to make it use the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
because the trait file is in the vendor folder and not tracked probably by the git repo

Answer (score -2):

```
$search = $request->get('search');

Events::whereRaw('title COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci LIKE ?', ['%' . $search . '%'])
    ->published()
    ->get();
```

Comment: Probably you should add a little more info to add some value to your answer and make it more useful for future readers !